# Apply background color to html cell in table based on its value via python

Tags: python, html, python-3.3

I'm writing a python script that writes an html table, and have not yet been able to figure out how to change the background color of a cell based on the value the tag will have. This question might not be very clear so let me illustrate:

```
the_table = ("""<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <td>values</td>
        <td>%s</td>
        <td>%s</td>
    </tr>
</table>""") % (value1, value2)
```

How do I add to the html code something to make the cell red if the values are less than 0, yellow if 0 and green if greater than 0?

I'm new to html, I know how to color the cell, but not if based on a value.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Apply the [`background-color`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-color) style depending on the value:

```
def get_color(value):
    return "green" if value > 0 else "red"

the_table = """<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <td>values</td>
        <td style="background-color: %(color1)s;">%(value1)s</td>
        <td style="background-color: %(color2)s;">%(value2)s</td>
    </tr>
</table>""" % {'value1': value1, 
               'value2': value2,
               'color1': get_color(value1),
               'color2': get_color(value2)}
```

Aside from that, think about using a [template engine](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Templating) (`jinja2` or `mako`, for example) instead of forming the HTML via string formatting.